# Is it possible to use an existing Facebook Connect session with Facebooker?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, session, facebook, facebooker

**Update:** Working as designed once I cleared my cookies. Doh!

I'm working on an app that for various reasons uses the Facebook
Javascript API to initiate a Facebook connect session. I'd like to be
able to use that session in a few rails methods using Facebooker.

The basic workflow is like this:

1. User goes to non-rails page and logs in to FB Connect via JS
2. User goes to another non-rails page and can view FB data such as
   name, profile pic
3. User goes to a rails based page - rails uses session created in
   step 1 to do some processing

My problem is in step 3. Facebooker detects the session fine, but when
I try to call a method like  facebook_session.user.name I get: Session
key invalid or no longer valid

If I go back to the url in step two, my session still works fine.

So is this a fundamental incompatibility, or is there some data I can
send to facebooker so that I can hook into the correct session? Maybe
my facebooker.yml needs tweaking?

Any thoughts are appreciated.

My facebooker.yml

```
development:
 api_key: redacted
 secret_key: redacted
 canvas_page_name: blah_blah
 callback_url: http://test.domain:3000
 pretty_errors: true
 set_asset_host_to_callback_url: true
 tunnel:
   public_host_username:
   public_host:
   public_port: 4007
   local_port: 3000
   server_alive_interval: 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gah! Always clear your cookies before posting on the interweb people.

The problem was with an existing facebooker-based session that was still around in my browser.

All working now.